# How to remove hello world thing on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, ios-simulator, default

[image: hello world thing on simulator]

**How can I remove "Hello, world!" on this simulator?** This is happening since I update Xcode and High Sierra (Xcode version 9.4, iOS version 11.4, macOS High Sierra version 10.13.5).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you started a new game project?  Look through the files...

Delete `helloLabel` from `GameScene.sks`